# log4 net multiple loggers vs single logger in an application?

Tags: c#, logging, log4net, log4net-configuration, log4net-appender

We have c# application with several different modules. We are using log4net for logging. What should be done to log the messages:

1. Create a centralized logging project: The application classes to use centralized logging project's dll's static methods to log the messages. So, no class in application creates the logger, all logging requirements to be fulfilled by this dll OR
2. All types in the application itself creating their own loggers: Easy to check which type generates which message, easy to manage different type of logging requirements i.e.we can throttle logging behavior of each type independently, like one class logging ALL logs but other only loggin ERROR.

What is the preferred practise?

The approach2 has its own benefit but approach1 looks clean as each class would no longer be responsible for calling "GetLogger(typeOf(className))".

What is the recommended way?

Comment: Really depends on what you want to do. I find 1 and 2 contradict each other. Sure having a centralized project keeps thing cleaner but forces all logging to be done with one configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on the usecase, when making a library it can make sense to use method 1. However when making a complex program method 2 will help you to manage different logger independently. Method 2 will give the also the option to log all in you project like method 1 does. However method 1 does not support differing on logger. So method 2 seems a better choice in most cases.